# Exploring User Activity Log

Tags: support

I was looking through Stack Exchange Data Explorer [Queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), and couldn't find any related to latest user activity stats. Is there a way to find:

- what users were most active in a particular Tag for the last month,
  week, day?
- what users were browsing new questions or edited answers queues on Stack Overflow in the last 5 min in a certain tag or in general?

Comment: SEDE is only updated weekly, FYI. Also, I don’t think they track individual views in the DB at all.

Answer (score 1):

We don't expose traffic logs, so specific per-user view data isn't available publicly.

As for user activity... that should be possible to write up, but it depends on what you mean by "active". Posting? Editing? Voting? (Voting by specific users is not discoverable through SEDE since that'd require exposing who voted on what, but you could potentially get aggregates like "X posts got upvoted", if I recall the public schema off the top of my head correctly.)

For example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/523974/potential-documentation-proposal-committers) aims to list users eligible to commit to a specific tag within [Documentation](//stackoverflow.com/documentation). You could extend it to look at other types of activity as well.